# Javascript map array with 'fromCharCode' (character length)

Tags: javascript

The following is from an interactive session in the Chrome console:

```
myarray
//-> [67, 65, 84]

String.fromCharCode(67)
//-> "C"

String.fromCharCode(67).length
//-> 1

String.fromCharCode(myarray[0])
//-> "C"

String.fromCharCode(myarray[0]).length
//-> 1

myarray.map(String.fromCharCode)
//-> ["C", "A", "T"]

myarray.map(String.fromCharCode)[0]
//-> "C"

myarray.map(String.fromCharCode)[0].length
//-> 3
```

Can anyone explain why the last operation returns `3`?

Comment: Firefox 4 also says "3" ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk4pA/))

Comment: @T.J. Crowder The presentation does lack some explanatory support but, though I was dubious at first, I'm hooked :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Very interesting question.**

And the answer is: The reason you're getting `3` at the end is that `fromCharCode` returns a string with *as many characters as there are arguments in the call* to it, and `map` calls the callback function with three arguments: The value of the element, the index of the element, and the object being traversed. Thus, a string with three characters, but not three readily-displayed characters. Tricky.

Specifically, we get `"C"` for the first argument; character 0 for the second argument (since we're looking at `[0]`; it would be 1 for `[1]`, etc.), and a character based on coercing the array into a number (using whatever rules `fromCharCode` uses for that; Šime Vidas says below that it'll do `ToUInt16` on it, which will result in `0`).

So, for instance:

```
> String.fromCharCode(67, 0, [67, 65, 84]).length
3
```

...just as with the call from `map`.

For clarity:

```
> String.fromCharCode(67, 0, [67, 65, 84]).length
3
> String.fromCharCode(67, 0, null).length
3
> String.fromCharCode(67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).length
7
```

If we ensure we only pass it the one argument at a time, we don't see that unexpected effect, so while using it directly gives us a result I think most of us wouldn't expect:

```
> [67, 65, 84].map(String.fromCharCode)
["C", "A", "T"]
> [67, 65, 84].map(String.fromCharCode)[0]
"C"
> [67, 65, 84].map(String.fromCharCode)[0].length
3
```

...this gives us a more easily-understood result:

```
> [67, 65, 84].map(function(value) { return String.fromCharCode(value); })
["C", "A", "T"]
> [67, 65, 84].map(function(value) { return String.fromCharCode(value); })[0]
"C"
> [67, 65, 84].map(function(value) { return String.fromCharCode(value); })[0].length
1
```

Comment: I was just starting to wonder that ... this is one of those cool things to know for parties etc.

Comment: Also this would be an great example application for the ".aritize()" utility that the [Functional](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) JavaScript library provides :-)

Comment: @Crowder So this: `[67, 65, 84].map(String.fromCharCode)[0]` will return this string: `"C"`, however this returns false: `[67, 65, 84].map(String.fromCharCode)[0] === "C"`. Great job JavaScript `:)`

Comment: @Crowder *"and a character based on coercing the array into a number"* - this is not fully correct. If you pass an array into fromCharCode, ToUInt16(arr) will be performed. A plain number coercion would result in NaN, whereas ToUInt16 returns 0 in that case.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: You caught me glossing over a detail. ;-) I've edited your notes in, thanks.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: *'So this: `[67, 65, 84].map(String.fromCharCode)[0]` will return this string: `"C"`'* No, it'll return `"C\u0000\u0000"` or similar (the console just isn't showing us that, because it doesn't show us literal notation for strings, it shows us the values of them in a display-like format), which isn't the same thing as `"C"`, hence your comparison returning `false`.

Comment: @Crowder Yes, it's unfortunate that you cannot get details about the console output by hovering over it (for instance), that would be a cool feature.

Comment: Note - on your comment "however this returns false: [67, 65, 84].map(String.fromCharCode)[0] === "C"" is how I got here in the first place :)

Answer (score 4):

I can't expand much on T.J. Crowder's great answer, but I can provide a workaround for this specific problem.

Rather than

```
myarray.map(String.fromCharCode);
```

Use

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(String, myarray).split("");
```

Aside from the benefit of returning the expected result, this also works without relying on the ECMAScript 5th Edition method, `Array.prototype.map`, thus making it more compatible.

Comment: For large strings `apply` will hit a RangeError if it exceeds the number of arguments

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem and found this thread. If you're into ES6, I propose this solution:

```
arr.map((c)=>String.fromCharCode(c));
```