# Efficient way to invoke fromCharCode on large data

Tags: javascript, performance

What I have: a string with numbers separated by spaces.

What I want: a string composed of `fromCharCode` applied to each number in the input.

```
var str = "72 69 76 76 79" ;
var arr = str.split(" ") ;
var num = arr.map(Number) ;
var txt = num.map(function(value) { return String.fromCharCode(value); }) ;
return txt.join('') ;
```

This code works, the result is the string `HELLO`, but in production the length of `str` will be in the millions so I need the most efficient translation of this.
(Note: The last assignment row looks a bit weird. It is to get around a quirk in `fromCharCode` well described by [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566937/javascript-map-array-with-fromcharcode-character-length).)

I don't see any way around the initial `split`, but I'm note sure if two consecutive `map` calls is the way to go. Would it be better to perform `Number` and `fromCharCode` in an explicit loop and translate one character at a time? I assume there's some overhead with `foreach`, but perhaps it's worth it to only run through the data once.

I've seen that `fromCharCode` accepts comma-separated lists of numbers, but I don't see how to translate my array of integers without introducing more traversing than the code above.

My js knowledge doesn't extend much beyond map and explicit loops. Is there a more modern - or less naive - approach? Preferably I want js vanilla.

Comment: Will each number in the string always be 2 digits long?

Comment: Where does this data comes from? Why is it a String? WIll this always be ascii? Also, what environment are you on and what do you try to improve: raw performances, or just to avoid the UI freezes in case you're in a browser?

Comment: @Nick: nope. There might be some higher numbers in there.

Comment: @Kaiido: The source is a legacy system. It's a string because it comes to the browser in an xhr body. The js will run in browsers.

Comment: "*It's a string because it comes to the browser in an xhr body.*" xhr can receive Blobs and ArrayBuffers, which would already leverage 2 heavy steps in your code. But anyway you are basically sending the UTF-8 representation of a 32bit Array representing an UTF-16 text... That's three unneeded steps. Just send the text directly as UTF-8...

Comment: @Kaiido: I really appreciate that you're trying to help me, but I'm not sure I understand what to do. Maybe I left out too much information in my previous comment. The data comes to the browser as an xml tag. I just assumed that xml always was String.

Answer (score -1):

The "fastest" way is usually the method that requires the least amount of "change" to your data.

That said, there is nothing wrong with your initial code and unless we are talking HUGE amounts of text, or the code needs to execute often, then it shouldn't be an issue.

If you need the extra performance, Regular Expressions could be the way to go. You skip initializing an Array and the instead of two mapping operations (one to number and another back to string), all that can be handled with a single callback:

```js
function CodeToChar(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w+(\s|$)/igm, function replacePart(part) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(part, 10));
  })
}
console.log(
  CodeToChar("72 69 76 76 79")
)
```